# Does word2vec work fine with a corpus with text in two languages?

Tags: java, word2vec

I would like to build a small search engine that recommends related words to the users. I think word2vec can help me to address this problem. In principle, this search engine is going to allow queries in English and German. My question is clear: Could word2vec work fine with a corpus that has contents in English but also in German at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I have used word vectors in **Turkish** with **English** for text classification. And it works well for my case. I think, you can use both language at same time.

Comment: @Jorgemar can you inform me, if it works well for German and English??

Comment: for sure, In case I come to know this, I will tell you.